# Angular2 custom pipe template error

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have created pipe in my application and placed this file in main app folder. And i included into my app.module.ts like below

```
import { DataFilterPipe } from './data-filter.pipe';
 declarations: [
        App,
        DataFilterPipe
    ],
```

and my pipe files like below,

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'dataFilter'
})
export class DataFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(array: any[], query: string): any {
        if (query) {
            return _.filter(array, row=>row.name.indexOf(query) > -1);
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

And my folder structure looks like,
[image]
And I  used this pipe into my sub folders but showing error like below,

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'dataFilter' could not be found ("
            </div>
            <table class="table table-striped"
                [ERROR ->][mfData]="data | dataFilter : filterQuery" #mf="mfDataTable"
                [mfRowsOnPage]="rowsOnPage" [(mfSort"): ng:///MasterModule/AdminUsersComponent.html@59:4
```

First I used like included into all the sub modules so it was working well without any issue. But when I create files to production it showed error like declared into 2 module so that I included in route module.
Please help me anyone to solve this issue.

Comment: `declarations: [...]` has to be a parameter to `@NgModule(...)`. Just adding it at random places won't do it. If you just omitted that part in the question, then it might be that the component where you use the pipe is in a different module than where the pipe is listed in declarations. In this case you need to add the module that contains the pipe to the module that contains the component that uses the pipel.

Comment: Is the `data-filter.pipe.ts` in the same folder like `app.module.ts`?

Comment: yes, i have created pipe in same folder of app.module.ts